# Relationship only displaying channel #

Tags: channel, relationships

I am a somewhat newbie with Expression engine but I cant seem to find a solution to this problem. I have a simple relationship between two channels and for some reason the correct channel # is the only think that is displayed. (Code below) Link to view the public page. Any help would be appreciated.

http://staging.stitchmedia.ca/ee/index.php/bookcase/circus-of-mirrors

Seems to be happening in two spots

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="adventure" url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
```

.... SOME HTML CODE HERE .....

```
{related_authors}
    <h2>{related_authors:author_name}</h2>
    <p>{related_authors:author_bio}</p>
{/related_authors}
```

.... SOME MORE HTML CODE HERE .....

```
{related_chapters}
    <li>
        <img src="{related_chapters:chapter_thumbnail}" alt="{related_chapters:chapter_title} Thumbnail" class="th-chapter-icon">
        <h4 class="th-chapter-title">{related_chapters:chapter_position}:{related_chapters:chapter_title}</h4>
        <span class="th-chapter-more">+</span>
        <div class="th-chapter-content">
            <img src="{related_chapters:chapter_image}" alt="{related_chapters:chapter_title} Thumbnail" class="th-chapter-icon">
            <p>{related_chapters:chapter_description}</p>
        </div>
    </li>
```

{/related_chapters}

Comment: Which version of EE are you using? EE just updated the relationship fieldtype in 2.6, so this question probably needs some clarification as to whether you are using the new code or the old.

Comment: Thats probably it, I downloaded EE 8 days ago, just before the new release and have been using the online guide which references 6.0.

Comment: In that case, I can't help as I haven't even used that fieldtype yet. It's brand new, so I bet community support is slow for this. You could likely post this in EllisLab's support system to get a quick answer. (And of couse post the answer back here if you do.)

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Using 2.6 fieldtypes in 2.5.5
Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments, this was due to using template tags for 2.6+ for an EE 2.5.5 site. Updating to EE 2.6+ or modifying templates tags for 2.5.5 fieldtypes fixes it.